# How to map `df` in vim to delete the file under cursor

Tags: vim

I know `gf` opens the file under cursor, which is so nice. But I want delete the file under cursor. Here are two questions.

1. Does `df` have any original(default) function in vim?
2. How to map `df` to `delete the file under cursor`?

Comment: Yes, `f{char}` is already a motion, see `:help f`. This seems… vaguely dangerous.

Comment: well, I will only apply this set to markdown file. It is very necessary to delete the pictures in the markdown file.

Comment: Do you want to *actually* "delete the file", "delete the `![xxx](yyy)` markup", or both? Do you want this to work on any notation or on a specific one? What did you try? Having it happen when you press `df` is the easy part and I think you should rewrite your question to focus on the hard part.

Comment: I just hope you never press `df` when your cursor is on a slash.

Comment: @Friedrich I find a solution and post it on this page.

Comment: Note that `df<char>` means "delete from the current cursor forward up to and including the first occurrence of <char> in the current line". That is classic Vi.

Answer (score 4):

Binding keys to blindly delete file is dangerous and should be avoided. On the other hand, it is not so hard to type such command interactively:

```
:!rm <ctrl-r><ctrl-f><enter>
```

So it takes only about eight key hits to do it safely.

Answer (score 1):

I want delete the image file of markdown.

well, here is my solution

```bash
noremap df :call system("rm -f ".expand("<cfile>"))<cr>
```

I press `df` when the cursor is on a slash, and nothing is deleted.